# Usage of GetApiKeys in Amazon SDK

Tags: c#, .net, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-sdk

I am trying to get the total count of api keys in my API gateway via SDK.
However I am unsure on the proper implementation of the parameters that the GetApiKeysRequest takes in. My main objective is to get the count of all API keys that are already existing for my account.

The code I have so far looks like this :

```
class Program
{
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var awsUserAccessKey = "xxxxx";

        var awsUserSecretKey = "yyyyyyyyyyy";

        var regionEndpoint = "us-west-2";

        var keysInRepository = new GetApiKeysRequest
        {
            CustomerId = "",
            IncludeValues = true||false,
            Limit=0,
            NameQuery = "",
            Position = ""
        };


        var client = new AmazonAPIGatewayClient(awsUserAccessKey, awsUserSecretKey, regionEndpoint);

        var apiKeys =client.GetApiKeys(keysInRepository);

        Console.Read();
    }
}
```

This code throws an error saying that The security token included in the request is invalid (Amazon.APIGateway exception).I am unsure on how to set the parameters for this request.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

For someone looking for a solution to similar problems, this worked :

```
        var awsUserAccessKey = "xxxx";
        var awsUserSecretKey = "yyyyy";
        var regionEndpointName = "us-west-2";
        var regionEndpoint = RegionEndpoint.GetBySystemName(regionEndpointName);

        var keysInRepository = new GetApiKeysRequest
        {
            Limit = 500

        };
        //define the key and its fields
        var client = new AmazonAPIGatewayClient(awsUserAccessKey, awsUserSecretKey, regionEndpoint);

        var apiKeys = client.GetApiKeys(keysInRepository);

        Console.WriteLine("Current number of api keys:{0}", apiKeys.Items.Count);
```

Answer (score 2):

Because the AmazonAPIGatewayClient you are using as described [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdkfornet/v3/apidocs/items/APIGateway/MAPIGatewayctorStringStringString.html) takes three string arguments and the last one is `awsSessionToken` i think you are confusing with this [one](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdkfornet/v3/apidocs/items/APIGateway/MAPIGatewayctorStringStringRegionEndpoint.html) which takes as third argument [RegionEndpoint](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdkfornet/v3/apidocs/items/Amazon/TRegionEndpoint.html)

Do something like that instead :

```
var client = new AmazonAPIGatewayClient(awsUserAccessKey, awsUserSecretKey, RegionEndpoint.USWest2);
```